# "getaddrinfo failed" on python proxy server

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I'm using python to try and make a proxy server just for fun. Everything seemed to work, but when I connected my computer to it it gave me an error for every request I made.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (listen_thread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\doubl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\doubl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "g:\My Drive\coding stuff\Projects\Transmission\chatroomsetup\proxyserver.py", line 42, in listen_thread
    my_socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname(webserver), port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I was following a tutorial that didn't do a very good job at commenting, so honestly I only get the general gist of what this code does.

Heres my listening thread

```
def listen_thread(client, client_address):
    while True:
       req = client.recv(8192).decode()
       if req:
        print(req)
        url = req.split('\n')[0].split(' ')[1]
        httppos = url.find('://')
        if httppos == -1:
            urlweb = url
        else:
            urlweb = url[httppos+3:]
        portpos = url.find(':')
        webserverpos = urlweb.find('/')
        if webserverpos == -1:
            webserverpos = len(urlweb)
        if portpos == -1 or (url[:portpos] != 'http' and url[:portpos] != 'https'):
            port = 80
        else:
            port = int(url[portpos+1:webserverpos])
        webserver = urlweb[:webserverpos]
        my_socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname(webserver), port))
        my_socket.send(req.encode())
        while True:
            data = my_socket.recv(8192)
            if data:
                client.send(data)
            else:
                break
```

If you need more comment and I'll update the code.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Print out the arguments you are giving to the function.

Comment: cc-api-data.adobe.io:443 is `webserver` and 80 is `port`, so that means it isnt actually finding the port, and the socket is trying to connect to the server plus the port as just the server, and the autoset 80 as the port. So I know the problem, I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: @NicholasPicklas: so you are basically asking how to get the host and port from a string of the form `"host:port"` ? Have a look at [split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all of the port code and replace it with `split`. Much easier and works better.